# how to write in jQuery thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

Tags: jquery

how to write in jQuery  thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

```
   thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
```

---

```
thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].typeahead({});
```

Comment: `$(thisRow).find('input').first()[0].typeahead({})`?

Comment: window.getproduct = function (thisRow){
 var one = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
alert(one); 
$.get('/api/product/productjson?search='+one, function(data){
    $('input',thisRow)[0].typeahead({
        source: data,
        autoSelect: true,
        displayText: function(item){ return item.name; },
        afterSelect: function(item) {
      \$thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = item.id;
      alert(item.product_name);
        },
    });
},'json');
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('input',thisRow)[0]
```

Comment: not working 
-----
window.getproduct = function (thisRow){

  var one = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
//alert(one);
  
$.get('/api/product/productjson?search='+one, function(data){
    $('input',thisRow)[0].typeahead({
        source: data,
        autoSelect: true,
        displayText: function(item){ return item.name; },
        afterSelect: function(item) {


      \$thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = item.id;

      alert(item.product_name);

        },
    });
},'json');

  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

`$(thisRow).find('input')[0]`